# How to combine two different type variables?

Tags: c

I have two functions, the body is exactly same, only the parameter is different:

```
int setCustomerUser(struct userCustomer *user, struct profile *data) {
        user->type = data->type;
        // ....  A
}

int setAdminUser(struct userAdmin *user, struct profile *data) {
        user->type = data->type;
        // ....  B
}
```

`A` and `B` are same.

`userCustomer` and `userAdmin` are basically same, except some different.

```
struct userCustomer {
    int type;
    char *name;
    char *mail;

    int gender;
    char *address;
    int point;
    // ....
}

struct userAdmin {
    int type;
    char *name;
    char *mail;

    int dept;
    // ....
}
```

So I would like to combine the two functions into one, something like this:

```
int setUser(void *user1, struct profile *data, int userType) {
        if(userType == 0) {
                struct userCustomer *user = (struct userCustomer *)user1;
        } else {
                struct userAdmin *user = (struct userAdmin *)user1;
        }

        user->type = data->type;
        // ...
}
```

But as you know C is not Python, it does not work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the `struct` definition for both? What other things are done inside that function?

Comment: Updated, other things inside the function are exactly same: set common vars

Comment: This might be a case for a macro.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What error message or output do you get?

Comment: Does `A, B` access `user->` in any way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `union` member in the `struct` like this:

```
struct user {
    int type;
    char *name;
    char *mail;

    union {
        struct {
            int gender;
            char *address;
            int point;
            // ....
        } customer;

        struct {
            int dept;
            // ....
        } admin;
    };
};
```

To distinguish values of both types, it makes sense to store the "type" right inside the `struct`. That's what `type` already does, even though I would use an `enum`.

You access the common parts like before:

```
user->type = ...;
```

And the special part like this (but you probably know this):

```
user->customer.gender = ...;

user->admin.dept = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the common fields into a common struct.

```
struct userCommon {
    int type;
    char *name;
    char *mail;
};

struct userCustomer {
    struct userCommon c;
    int gender;
    char *address;
    int point;
};

struct userAdmin {
    struct userCommon c;
    int dept;
};

int userCommon_setType(struct userCommon *c, struct profile *data) {
      c->type = data->type;
      return 62;
}

int userCustomer_setType(struct userCustomer *user, struct profile *data) {
      return userCommon_setType(&user->c, data);
}

int userAdmin_setType(struct userCustomer *user, struct profile *data) {
      return userCommon_setType(&user->c, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the prototype with 2 parameters are 2 struct instead of using *userType*

The example:

```
int setUser(userCustomer *user, userAdmin *admin, struct profile *data) 
{
    if(user != NULL) 
    {
        user->type = data->type;
    } 
    if (admin != NULL)
    {
        admin->type = data->type;
    }
            // ...
}
```